# How to know if the terminal is processing an installation? Is this terminal hang situation? What can we do in such a situation?

Tags: command-line, msi

I am installing an application on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Now I have given the following command and the terminal is not doing anything after certain process.
Nothing is happening, I mean the text is not moving as it usually does when it installs something or is running programs, etc
How can we establish if it is still installing the program? Is it terminal hang?
Any help is most welcome. Thank you!!

root@chess-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:/home/chess/Downloads# wine msiexec /i InfinityChess.msi
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0068:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0068:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0080:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0080:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0078:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0078:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00c8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00c8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00d0:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00d0:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0118:fixme:process:SetProcessMitigationPolicy (0, 0031FE44, 8): stub
0120:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 00000000006E0000 0 000000000021E8F0 4 stub
0120:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0120:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0120:fixme:seh:WerSetFlags (2) stub
0120:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000000000000 1 0000000000000000 0 stub
013c:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
013c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
013c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
013c:fixme:seh:WerSetFlags (2) stub
013c:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 00000000 1 00000000 0 stub

Comment: It's not installing anything. All that 'fixme' output is telling you that application is currently incompatible with Wine.

Comment: Ok!! Thank you for telling me this. In such a case the process should auto terminate and give out a message "This program is incompatible with Wine" That would make decision process much easier. Thank you very much, I have terminated the terminal now. :)